# user agent in safari to iphone

Tags: iphone, safari, user-agent

I've changed the User Agent in Safari browser to iPhone but nothing happens. Am I misunderstanding the use of this? I'm running Safari in a window environment.

Thanks,
rod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'nothing happens' means what? What are you expecting? After changing user agent I need to force refresh the webpage, and go to mobile version of website again.

E.g. when with firefox's user-agent, http://m.google.com redirects to another page. But with iPhone's it shows original mobile website. The user agent for iPhone 3 is as follows:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16
```

Comment: how do you force a refresh of the web page in safari